# Finite Growable Array in Scala

Tags: scala, extend, arraybuffer

I would like to be able to grow an Array-like structure up to a maximum size, after which the oldest (1st) element would be dropped off the structure every time a new element is added.  I don't know what the best way to do this is, but one way would be to extend the ArrayBuffer class, and override the += operator so that if the maximum size has been reached, the first element is dropped every time a new one is added.  I haven't figured out how to properly extend collections yet.  What I have so far is:

```
class FiniteGrowableArray[A](maxLength:Int) extends scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer {
    override def +=(elem:A): <insert some return type here> = {
        // append element
        if(length > maxLength) remove(0)
        <returned collection>
    }
}
```

Can someone suggest a better path and/or help me along this one?  NOTE: I will need to arbitrarily access elements within the structure multiple times in between the += operations.

Thanks

Comment: sounds like a [ring buffer](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Circular_buffer)

Comment: @ziggystar.  Agreed, sounds like a ring buffer might do the trick...

Comment: @ziggstar.  ...however, would this give me O(1) access to random elements in the structure, or is it geared more toward enqueue/dequeue type processing?

Comment: A ring buffer, if implemented as an array, can give O(1) indexed access. It just needs to add a `first` index to the argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have discussed, you want a ring buffer.  However, you also have to decide if you actually want all of the collections methods or not, and if so, what happens when you filter a ring buffer of maximum size N--does it keep its maximum size, or what?

If you're okay with merely being able to *view* your ring buffer as part of the collections hierarchy (but don't want to use collections efficiently to generate new ring buffers) then you can just:

```
class RingBuffer[T: ClassManifest](maxsize: Int) {
  private[this] val buffer = new Array[T](maxsize+1)
  private[this] var i0,i1 = 0
  private[this] def i0up = { i0 += 1; if (i0>=buffer.length) i0 -= buffer.length }
  private[this] def i0dn = { i0 -= 1; if (i0<0) i0 += buffer.length }
  private[this] def i1up = { i1 += 1; if (i1>=buffer.length) i1 -= buffer.length }
  private[this] def i1dn = { i1 -= 1; if (i1<0) i1 += buffer.length }   
  private[this] def me = this

  def apply(i: Int) = {
    val j = i+i0
    if (j >= buffer.length) buffer(j-buffer.length) else buffer(j)
  }
  def size = if (i1<i0) buffer.length+i1-i0 else i1-i0
  def :+(t: T) = {
    buffer(i1) = t
    i1up; if (i1==i0) i0up
    this
  }
  def +:(t: T) = {
    i0dn; if (i0==i1) i1dn
    buffer(i0) = t
    this
  }
  def popt = {
    if (i1==i0) throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException
    i1dn; buffer(i1)
  }
  def poph = {
    if (i1==i0) throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException
    val ans = buffer(i0); i0up; ans
  }
  def seqView = new IndexedSeq[T] {
    def apply(i: Int) = me(i)
    def length = me.size
  }
}
```

Now you can use this easily directly, and you can jump out to IndexedSeq when needed:

```
val r = new RingBuffer[Int](4)
r :+ 7 :+ 9 :+ 2
r.seqView.mkString(" ")    // Prints 7 9 2
r.popt                     // Returns 2
r.poph                     // Returns 7
r :+ 6 :+ 5 :+ 4 :+ 3
r.seqView.mkString(" ")    // Prints 6 5 4 3 -- 7 fell off the end
0 +: 1 +: 2 +: r
r.seqView.mkString(" ")    // Prints 0 1 2 6 -- added to front; 3,4,5 fell off
r.seqView.filter(_>1)      // Vector(2,6)
```

and if you want to put things back into a ring buffer, you can

```
class RingBufferImplicit[T: ClassManifest](ts: Traversable[T]) {
  def ring(maxsize: Int) = {
    val rb = new RingBuffer[T](maxsize)
    ts.foreach(rb :+ _)
    rb
  }
}
implicit def traversable2ringbuffer[T: ClassManifest](ts: Traversable[T]) = {
  new RingBufferImplicit(ts)
}
```

and then you can do things like

```
val rr = List(1,2,3,4,5).ring(4)
rr.seqView.mkString(" ")            // Prints 2,3,4,5
```